# What tyre tread would be best suited to an off road robot expected to deal with frequently muddy conditions?

Tags: wheel

I'm looking to potentially build an autonomous robot that will frequently venture off road, and remain autonomous for up to 6 hours at a time. I've found limited information however about the best tyre tread for this purpose, what could be most suitable?

I'm especially looking for a tread pattern that won't need regular cleaning, to save setting this up automatically (a tread that gets "clogged" very quickly clearly won't be that effective at tackling tough terrain autonomously.)

Comment: for the clogging, 'ramped' threads work well, as well as a harder compound which will reduce stickyness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is very little difference between a robotic off road vehicle and a normal vehicle with a driver. What kind of vehicles are suitable for off-road conditions?

Why - tractors of course!

[image: Tractor]

Look at those bad boys! Great for all around the farm. Nobody seems to talk about the importance of cleaning the mud off them, except to read the part number to order replacements.

In fact, why not other off-road vehicles? Like Land Rovers:

[image: Land Rover]

They seem to be able to undertake long expeditions without requiring cleaning.

Or Monster trucks:

[image: Monster Truck]

What you'll notice about the treads on these types of tyres is the alternating half-chevron patterns. They point in such a way that the mud sliding on the tyre is always pushed towards the outside of the tyre, eventually falling off. In a way they're self cleaning.

Comment: As a mountain biker, I concur. Also anything with lots of knobbly tread will be nearly as good as the chevrons.